# Delay in recieving FCM notification in device

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to implement firebase push notification inside my android application. The problem I'm facing is that when I send a notification from the firebase console it takes 3 minutes of delay to be received on the device. I tried testing it on the emulator as well as on mobile too. Please do let me know if anyone has any knowledge about it